# phpMyAdmin application crashes with "Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: mysqli_result::data_seek()"

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin

When I run the query on phpMyAdmin, I get the following error. What is the error in the query I am using?

Query:

`SELECT hashtag, total, tarih FROM social_trend WHERE tarih > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5`

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: mysqli_result::data_seek(): Argument #1 ($offset) must be greater than or equal to 0 in 
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php:270 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php(270): mysqli_result->data_seek(-1) 
#1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(2726): PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->dataSeek(Object(mysqli_result), -1) 
#2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php(4464): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->dataSeek(Object(mysqli_result), -1) 
#3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php(4203): PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getSortedColumnMessage(Object(mysqli_result), 'total') 
#4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(1669): PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable(Object(mysqli_result), Array, Array, true) 
#5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(1470): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(Object(PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results), './themes/pmahom...', NULL, Array, false, 0, 0, true, Object(mysqli_result), Array, true) 
#6 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(2255): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForNoResultsReturned(Array, '808rpg', 'social_trend', NULL, 0, Object(PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results), NULL, './themes/pmahom...', NULL, Object(mysqli_result), 'SELECT hashtag,...', NULL) 
#7 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\import.php(758): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(Array, false, '808rpg', 'social_trend', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'db_structure.ph...', './themes/pmahom...', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SELECT hashtag,...', NULL, NULL) 
#8 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbi\DbiMysqli.php on line 270
```

Comment: It looks like a bug with phpMyAdmin. Please report it as a bug to them

Comment: Yes the problem is caused by phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 version. Installing version 4.9.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in MySQL8.0. On an empty table it throws this error.
I turned back to MySQL 5.7 and have no issues so far ))

Comment: Since the person asking the question didn't post their phpMyAdmin version or their MySQL version, it is cool you offered a solution without requiring those. However, the user found that the solution was to downgrade phpMyAdmin rather than MySQL. Perhaps present your answer more as "worked for me" and consider next time posting YOUR phpMyAdmin version as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184263/phpmyadmin-application-crashes-with-fatal-error-uncaught-valueerror-mysqli-re